# How does gcc recognize that -lfl corresponds to flex library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

when i compile lex.yy.c with lfl gcc recognizes that some .a file of the flex library might be needed to be linked with my code. similarly for yacc we specify the -ly compiler option.

in other words if i create a library, abc.a i want gcc to recognize that whenever a program is compiled with -labc it should link with the library abc.a. what configuration changes need to be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The yacc library is named `liby.so`, and lives in something like `/usr/lib`, which is a directory that `ld` knows about.

Your abc library should be named `libabc.so` (or ".a" for a static lib), and should be placed in a directory that is searched by `ld`.

To add `/home/foo/libs` to the list of directories searched, add `-L/home/foo/libs` to the `ld` command.

Comment: OK cool, or add the folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./libs

Comment: `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is mainly used as a hack at runtime, to use shared libraries in directories that the runtime linker doesn't know about. I don't know if it has any effect on `ld`.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not affect the linker.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to configure anything. Call your library libabc.a, then use the command line:

```
gcc ... -L<path-to-libabc.a> -labc
```

Comment: I think without further precaution this will still pick an `.so` named `libabc.so` which may be located alongside the `libabc.a` ...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want GCC to recognise the library abc and link it via `-labc`, assuming abc is a static library, make sure your library file/archive abc is named `libabc.a`, and it is either located in one of the directories GCC searches for `.a` files, or you add a `-L` flag where the parameter is the directory where `libabc.a` is located in.